# Is it true: $\int ( \int f(u,z) d\mu(u))^2 dz \leq \|\mu \|_{TV} \int ( \int f(u,z) du)^2 dz$?

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory, statistics, measurable-functions

I am trying to understand if for a measurable continuous nonnegative function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu(A)>0$ for any measurable set on the Borel sigma-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ and $ \| \cdot \|_{TV}$ total variation distance, it holds:

$$\int \bigg( \int f(u,z) d\mu(u) \bigg)^2 dz \leq \|  \mu  \|_{TV} \int \bigg( \int f(u,z) du \bigg)^2 dz$$

If you consider that the total variation distance as the supremum metric for measures this seems to me just Holder inequality.

Comment: No way! Think of a counter-example where $\int f(u,z)du=0$ for all $z$.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that $f$ is nonnegative for any $z$, is then the statement true?

Comment: Still false. There are counter-example in which $\mu=\delta_0$.

Comment: Are there minimal conditions to make this true? (I can also assume that $\mu$ is non-degenerate, in essence a nicely enough measure)

Comment: I am not convinced this is true. If $f(u,z) = f(z-u)$ then you get for an arbitrary signed measure $\mu$, by Young's inequality: $\| f*\mu\|_2 \leq \| f \|_2 \|\mu\|_{TV}$. See also pp. 391 [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-41/issue-1/Convergence-of-latent-mixing-measures-in-finite-and-infinite-mixture/10.1214/12-AOS1065.full).

Comment: I also found this interesting theorem that I believe contains the answer: [here](https://qnlw.info/post/youngs-inequality/)

Comment: I made a slight mistake in stating my claim. I calibrated it and posted it as an answer, along with a proof.

Answer (score 3):

> **Claim.** Let $\mu$ be a finite non-negative Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Then the followings are equivalent:
>
> 1. For any compactly supported continuous $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to [0, \infty)$,
>    $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x, z) \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x)\right)^2 \, \mathrm{d}z \leq \mu(\mathbb{R}) \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x, z) \, \mathrm{d}x\right)^2 \, \mathrm{d}z. \tag{1}\label{eq:main} $$
> 2. There exists a Borel-measurable $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
>    $$ 0 \leq g(x) \leq \sqrt{\smash[b]{\mu(\mathbb{R})}} \qquad\text{and}\qquad \mu(\mathrm{d}x) = g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x . $$

*Proof.* The direction $(\impliedby)$ is easy, so we only prove the direction $(\implies)$.

First, consider $f(x, z) = \varphi(x)\eta(z)$ where $\varphi, \eta \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ are non-negative and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \eta(z)^2 \, \mathrm{d}z = 1$. Then $\eqref{eq:main}$ is recast as

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x) \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x) \leq \sqrt{\smash[b]{\mu(\mathbb{R})}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x) \, \mathrm{d}x . \tag{2}\label{eq:2} $$

Since $\eqref{eq:2}$ holds for any non-negative $\varphi \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$, it immediately follows that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mathrm{d}x$, and the corresponding Radon–Nikodym derivative satisfies

$$ 0 \leq \frac{\mathrm{d}\mu}{\mathrm{d}x} \leq \sqrt{\smash[b]{\mu(\mathbb{R})}}. $$

Now the desired claim follows by setting $g = \frac{\mathrm{d}\mu}{\mathrm{d}x}$.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but your theorem is clearly not true in view of the convolution case that I pointed out above. You can certainly think of functions $f(x,z)=f(x-z)$ (e.g. gaussian kernel) such that for general signed measures (no bounded density needed, not even absolute continuity wrt the Lebesgue measure) the inequality is true. This violates your theorem.

Comment: Just to make it clear: (cf. [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-41/issue-1/Convergence-of-latent-mixing-measures-in-finite-and-infinite-mixture/10.1214/12-AOS1065.full) pp. 391) for an arbitrary (signed) measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and a function $f \in \mathbb{L}_2 (\mathbb{R})$, there holds $\| \mu * f \|_2 \leq |\mu| \| f\|_2$ ($|\mu|$ total variation measure).

Comment: @GrandesJorasses, In my claim, I assume the inequality $\text{(1)}$ holds for very general form of function $f(x, z)$. (I could not find any specific condition you imposed on $f$, except than non-negativity and continuity.) So my answer does not contract whatever we have in the convolution case. If you want to further restrict the class of functions $f$ to be tested, then I can envision that a much broader class of $\mu$ may satisfy the given condition. (Less constraints means more choices!)